# Should I delete incorrect comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, deleted-comments

A comment to this [answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11048/is-there-a-typical-settings-order-before-shooting/11052#11052) is incorrect.  Should I delete it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can - it's common practice if something one writes is completely wrong, and nothing is to be gained from keeping it there.

However, if there are replies to the comment (as there are in your case), and the mistake you made is likely to be common, it may be worth leaving it in place to preserve the meaning of the conversation. It's up to you.

Comment: Thank you.  I will leave the comment there.

Comment: If only there would be some way to clean up. [;-)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83480/add-possibility-to-remove-comment-noise-fancy-edition)

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't bother, particularly since somebody has responded to the comment and you've cleared up the position.  It's a bit like deleting half a conversation.  Leaving the comment there, may also help somebody in the future not make the same mistake again.