# Can moderators see what answer/comment flags are applied to?

Tags: discussion, flags

In my personal "Flag Summary" page, submitted flags are grouped by question. The problem is, the page doesn't actually show whether you flagged the question, an answer, or a comment.

As an example, the following flag was added to a comment:

[image: Flagged comment showing up in "Flag Summary"]

Yet, clicking the link brings me directly to the answer, and gives no indication as to whether the flag was added to the answer itself, or one of its three comments.

Are moderators at least able to see which target the flag was applied to?

Comment: They are grouped per post in the queue. I've never really paid attention, but I thought they were grouped per post in the flagging history too. Are you sure you're not just confused because of the lack of indication if it is a question or answer that is linked? (If you flag a question, it links directly to the question - if you flag an answer, there *will* be an answer ID at the end of the URL to link directly to the answer.)

Comment: @animuson I'm more interested in in the lack of indication whether an _answer_ or _comment_ was flagged. I added an example to the question that should clarify what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in the moderator dashboard the title of a post is displayed in blue if the question was flagged and in gray if an answer was flagged.  Comments are displayed in the same style as on a question or answer, so it's even more obvious when a flagged post is a comment.

Comment: Do you think you could add a screenshot of what a flagged item looks like from the moderator's side? [As someone put it so well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203211/flagging-multiple-comments-versus-flagging-the-whole-post-for-moderator-attentio), "Much of the flagging and review system is still a black box to a low/mid rep user".

Comment: @IQAndreas No, sorry. We're really not supposed to reveal information in the moderator dashboard.

Comment: Not even a sample _Lorem ipsum_ flagged item? Oh well, all the more reason for me to work hard towards becoming a moderator so I can see the interface for myself. ;)