# How to process off-topic discussions in comments

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags, not-constructive

Just going through my usual [SO Hitlist](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-5..-2%20answers%3A..1%20is%3Aquestion%20hasaccepted%3Ano%20closed%3Ano%20duplicate%3Ano%20migrated%3Ano%20wiki%3Ano) until I saw [this massive debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065252/why-do-try-blocks-reduce-speed-of-my-program/7065409#7065409) in the comments:

[image: screenshot of comments]

20 comments, of which maybe 2 are on-topic, are arguing about the ethics of voting to balance or the validity of the answer.

So far, I've [flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/4272600) 2 of comments as "not constructive", but it would be *extremely tedious* to flag every single one of them (including the 5-second cooldown).

**Question:** As a <1k user, what should/can I do about extended discussions in comments?

Comment: Another potential dupe... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203211/flagging-multiple-comments-versus-flagging-the-whole-post-for-moderator-attentio/203215#203215

Comment: @Catija So this is where all the duplicate loops come from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a moderator looks at a flag and decides whether or not it is worth acting on, often he or she is not simply looking at the question/answer/post in question, but the context it is in. So if you flag a comment as, say, obsolete, a moderator will likely look to see just what makes the comment obsolete.

When you flag a comment for some reason - obsolete, too chatty, not constructive, etc. - it may not be the only comment that is obsolete/too chatty/not constructive. Fortunately,

1. It is very easy to see all the other comments.
2. It takes only one more click by a moderator to delete a comment.

So it seems likely that a moderator will delete the other comments that need to be deleted, too, not just the one(s) you flagged.

Some other things to note:

- You can raise a custom flag if you want, telling the moderators that the entire conversation needs to be dealt with. See [In a string of comments, including junk, should I flag the individual comments, or leave a custom flag on the post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243178/in-a-string-of-comments-including-junk-should-i-flag-the-individual-comments?lq=1).
- If a post gets 20 or more comments, [an automatic flag is raised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101531/when-comments-exceed-20?lq=1). So in many situations, a mod will be aware that there's a large number of comments. That's not to say that you *shouldn't* flag comments, but know that the number of comments is acknowledged.

Comment: Honestly, that link you posted seems to make this a dupe... I'm also pretty certain I've seen this question in the past.

Comment: @Catija Yeah, it looks like it.

Answer (score 2):

If an entire conversation needs to be flagged, flag the question or answer it is on and use the custom reason (flag for moderator attention) and ask that a mod remove the off-topic content in the discussion.

It is not recommended to flag every comment as it can annoy mods. If you flag the post, they get one flag and they can look at it as a whole.